# how to set color Gradient for carbonTabSwipeNavigation CarbonKit Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, carbonkit

I am new to iOS.I want to apply gradient colors on CarbonTabSwipeNavigation.I tried to apply the gradient to the toolbar of CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, but it is not happening
I have tried with Static Colore Code

```
carbonTabSwipeNavigation.toolbar.isTranslucent = true 
var color1 = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#00275E")
carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.backgroundColor = color1
carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setIndicatorColor(UIColor.white) //tabBar font
carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setSelectedColor(UIColor.white, font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14))
```

Comment: Consider marking an answer as correct to expand the visibility of the question: [stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

**First, add these extensions in your project.**

```
extension UINavigationBar {

    func setGradientBackground(colors: [UIColor]) {

        var updatedFrame = bounds
        updatedFrame.size.height += self.frame.origin.y
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer(frame: updatedFrame, colors: colors)

        setBackgroundImage(gradientLayer.createGradientImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    }
}

extension UIView {

    func setGradientBackgroundOnView(colors: [UIColor]) {

        var updatedFrame = bounds
        //    updatedFrame.size.height += self.frame.origin.y
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer(frame: updatedFrame, colors: colors)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}

extension CAGradientLayer {

    convenience init(frame: CGRect, colors: [UIColor]) {
        self.init()
        self.frame = frame
        self.colors = []
        for color in colors {
            self.colors?.append(color.cgColor)
        }
        startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
    }

    func createGradientImage() -> UIImage? {

        var image: UIImage? = nil
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            render(in: context)
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }

}
```

**Then call this method as your requirement.**

**Example**:- If you want to set a `gradient` color on `navigationbar` of your app then call use this

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setGradientBackground(colors: [UIColor.black, UIColor.red])
```